# Bluetooth LE on iOS10 strange behavior

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I found out that when an iPhone is updating a local characteristic value, and also listen to notification for that characteristic, he will get notified even the fact that **he was the one** that updated the value, so the delegate :

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
```

Will be called, even that I was the one who change the value, and not the remote server (ble device). When the remote side send data, I will also get this delegate. **Is it the way it should be ? I don't remember so .**

I found out the same behavior on *other* 3rd apps that scan for Bluetooth LE.

I also found out that for some reason my code is not always get the delegate , maybe I am doing things wrong here:

```
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {


        let foundName=peripheral.name
        let deviceName = "Name"

       if foundName?.range(of: deviceName) != nil
        {
                        self.centralManager.stopScan()
                        self.peripheral = peripheral
                        self.peripheral.delegate = self
                        self.centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
                        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "Bluetooth"), object: "Detected")

        }
}


    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {

         peripheral.discoverServices( nil)
    }



     func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {

          for service in peripheral.services!
         {

            let thisService = service as CBService
            print(thisService.uuid.uuidString)

            if thisService.uuid.uuidString == serviceUUID {
                 peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: thisService)
            }

        }
    }


    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

        for charateristic in service.characteristics!
        {
            let thisCharacteristic = charateristic as CBCharacteristic



            // check for data characteristic
            if thisCharacteristic.uuid.uuidString == characteristicUUID {

                print("REGISTERED CHARACTERISTIC:",thisCharacteristic)
                 self.peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: thisCharacteristic)
                self.characteristic=thisCharacteristic
                 isConnected=true
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "Bluetooth"), object: "Connected")

            }
        }            
    }


    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {


           if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == characteristicUUID {
             if let str = NSString(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
             {                   
                print("BLE:DATAIN:",str )
                 NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "Bluetooth"), object: str)

             }

          }                 
    }



    func sendData(data:String)
    {
        if(peripheral != nil)
        {
            print("BLE:SENT")  
            var bytesData = [UInt8](data.utf8)
            let writeData = NSData (bytes: &bytesData, length: bytesData.count)
             peripheral.writeValue(writeData as Data, for: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)
         }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe the peripheral sends a notification back when it gets a write request?

Comment: No, that was the first thing I'v checked

Comment: You appear to have spent a lot of time investigating this so perhaps you are correct, but I have not seen this in my testings. I have been using CoreBluetooth for a long time and have also spent a lot of time testing against iOS 10. The only "major" issue that I discovered was that Apple added so that you get a false acknowledgement on written packets regardless of which write type you specify.

Comment: @Anton , did you handle also the hardware ? if you develop your own chip you will have to face these things. Anyway , your platform is great :)

Comment: @Curnelious , yes I also do hardware and firmware for our products, but obviously we don't do our own BLE chips. But anyhow, I still can say that on our setup, when writing to a characteristic, we do not get an immediate notification if we are also already subscribed to it. But in your second answer you instead say that it happens when you actually set the notification status, which would explain why I am not seeing this behavior. But on the other hand it sort of contradict your first question :P
BTW, I don't quite understand what you mean by "your platform" in your comment above though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a day investigation, both the hardware chip and the iOS, I realized that the notify update- will notify you when there is a new value.

So, whats a new value  ?

Its when the previous value is different from the current value.

For some hardware configurations, the previous value is kept on cache even after reset, and iOS will see it as a new value, even though the hardware was not updated it at all (!)

**So when you register to notifications, iOS will check the initial value** , and if it holds something other then zero/nil , a delegate will be called.

Its your job to clean the previous cached value in the chip in some way.

In general, I found out (maybe too late) that the **best practice is to connect and stay connected as long as the app is running**. This will eliminate all sorts of problems that happens when you connect/disconnect every time you need to send data.

**Conclusion:** connect once, when disconnected for any reason -reset your hardware automatically (using the host controller software)